# Spring data jpa persist nested changes

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 classes:

Record/ Profile / Options

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Record")
public class Record implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="ProfileId")
    private Profile profile;

    ....

}

@Entity
@Table(name="Profile")
public class Profile implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="OptionId")
    private Option option;

    ....

}


@Entity
@Table(name="Option")
public class Option implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    ....

}
```

let's say the original option is "50M" and then I change the record1.profile1.option to "10M"

Also when I do `record1.setId(null);recordRepository.save(record1);`
I want to create an new entry from record1(as a change history).

In this case because the option is nested, the cascade type of merge will not persist the changes happened in profile. Thus when I get the record back, it will still say that `recordNew.profile1.option` is 50M

But if I change the cascadeType to `CascadeType.ALL` or `CascadeType.PERSIST`in the Record class, when I try to save the new entry, it seems Spring Data JPA will complains about detached property as: `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.test.lalala.profile.Profile`

Is there a way that I could fix this?

Comment: Please show the `@Id` properties of the entities in your post.